# Prove that $\log(n^n)=\Theta(\log(n!))$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm having problem proving that $\log(n^n)=\Theta(\log(n!))$

I tried to use Stirling's formula but it seems it doesn't help me in this case.

This is what I wrote :

$$n \to \infty : \frac{\log(n!)}{\log(n^n)}=\frac{\log(\frac{\sqrt {2\pi n}}{e^n }.n^n)}{\log(n^n)}$$
Now what?  nothing can be erased ... nothing can be made more simple ( Or maybe I don't know it)
Any idea?

Comment: $\log(n^n)=n\cdot\log(n)$. $\log(n!)=\log(1)+\cdots+\log(n)$. Have you tried sth like this?

It would also be nice to include you Stirling attempts in the question

Comment: @MichaelFreimann no... but how is this useful?

Comment: @PaoloMolina Given that Stirling's formula is canonically an asymptotic expression for $\log(n!)$, it's hard for us to guess what difficulty you encountered in using it.  Without more details it seems extremely straightforward.  But also there is a simple argument that doesn't require the precision of Stirling.

Comment: Consider the second equality and just take $\sum_{i>n/2}^n \log(i)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I adapted my answer for you using an [older Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn):

$$\log(n!) = \log(1) + \log(2) + \dots + \log(n-1) + \log(n)$$

**Upper bound** can be calculated using Sterling's approximation:

$$\log(1) + \dots + \log(n) \leq \log(n) + \dots + \log(n)
                                \text{ or } \boxed{n\log(n)}$$

**Lower bound** can be determined by reasoning: your answer will be the full expression after dropping the first half:

\begin{align*}
{} \log(1) + \dots + \log(\frac{n}{2}) + \dots + \log(n) \\
{} \geq \log(\frac{n}{2}) + \dots + \log(n) \\
{} \geq \log(\frac{n}{2}) + ... + \log(\frac{n}{2}) \text{ or } \boxed{\frac{n\log(n/2)}{2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: You can also use Stirling's approximation for the lower bound (but it requires a slightly more complete version of Stirling's approximation).

Comment: They're equivalent, if $f=\Theta(g)$, then $g=\Theta(f)$.  Also, remember your log rules, $n\log n=\log(n^n)$.

Comment: Oh, my bad!!! now i understand it !!! Thank you !

Comment: $f=\mathcal{O}(g)$ is equivalent to $g=o(f)$ hence the equivalence in Theta notaion.